# Radioactive Decay Calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus

After 2 mins, there is 4.1g of a substance left. One minute later (at t=3 mins), there is 3.4g left. How do I find the half-life of the substance and the original amount present?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. You will find that questions of the sort "Here is my assignment, work it for me" will be poorly received. Here is a [guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to asking a good question.

Comment: $$4.1\times 2^-\left(\dfrac{1\text{ minute}}{\text{half-life}}\right) = 3.4$$ $$\dfrac{1\text{ minute}}{\text{half-life}} = 0.27$$  $$\text{half-life} = 3.7\text{ minutes}$$

Comment: @CountIblis:  That is not correct  It claims that if the half life were 1 minute the amount would double in a minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for the exponential growth/decay model:

$$y=Ce^{kt}$$
$C$ is the initial amount (the amount of the substance present at time equals zero). $t$ is time which is the independent variable. $k$ is a constant.

In the case of your problem, $t=0$ corresponds to $0$ minutes. Using the given data, we get a system of equations with two unknowns that can be solved:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
4.1=Ce^{k2}\\
3.4=Ce^{k3}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

$$
\frac{4.1}{e^{k2}}=\frac{3.4}{e^{k3}}\implies k=\ln{\frac{3.4}{4.1}},\\
C=\frac{4.1}{e^{\ln{\frac{3.4}{4.1}}\cdot 2}}=\frac{4.1^3}{3.4^2}.
$$

Your model now should look like this:

$$
y=\frac{4.1^3}{3.4^2}\left(\frac{3.4}{4.1}\right)^t.
$$
Your task now is to find the time it takes for the substance to be reduced in half (that's what the half-life, $t_{1/2}$, is):

$$
\frac{\frac{4.1^3}{3.4^2}}{2}=\frac{4.1^3}{3.4^2}\left(\frac{3.4}{4.1}\right)^{t_{1/2}}\implies\\
t_{1/2}=\log_{\frac{3.4}{4.1}}{\frac12}=\frac{\ln{\frac{1}{2}}}{\ln{\frac{3.4}{4.1}}}\approx 3.7\ min.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Can you give me some hints on how to solve that equation? Thanks

Comment: I edited my post. Take a look.